# Splinter in Rasberry Pi 5

Tags: pi, splinter

I am having issues running a very basic script on my rasberry pi

```
from splinter import Browser


browser = Browser('chrome')

# Visit Google
browser.visit("https://www.google.com")

#
# import time
# time.sleep(10)

# Close the browser
browser.quit()
```

This is the error message I'm getting. wondering if someone had an idea on how to work around it?

```
python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py", line 38, in get_path
    path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Fipython3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/selenium_manager.py", line 86, in driver_location
    args = [str(self.get_binary()), "--browser", browser]
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is being ran off a virtual environment.

1- making sure all libraries were installed correctly.
2- doing this in another env

---

Expectations : for the browser to run and show Google.Com

Comment: Often Python problems with a system that should "just work" are down to using the wrong version of Python.  It looks like you're using 3.1x - isn't that rather old now?

Comment: just updated to 3.9 but still the same issue.  however ,I noticed that when running without installing Selenium the error message is different 

line 128, in Browser
    raise DriverNotFoundError(f"Driver for {driver_name} was not found.")
splinter.exceptions.DriverNotFoundError: Driver for chrome was not found.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help btw !. sorry if it's a dumb question , just getting started

Comment: Could you edit your question to add the new error, and what you do differently to get it?

Comment: Also add the link to the Splinter docs you are reading.

Comment: On a Pi 5 Selenium should work natively, but if you are happy to try other things, it should work via Docker as well, and that might be more "plug and play".